# How to create multi iterator and conditions in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iterator

How can I make a for loop with multiple conditions in python similar to other languages?

```
for ( i = 0, j=10; i<10 && j>0; i++, j-- )
```

or a bit more complex

```
for ( i = 0, j=10; i<10 && j>0 && flag; i+=3, j+=2 )

for ( i = 0, j=10; i<10 && j>0 && i<j; i+=3, j+=2 )
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip should help you here

Comment: need something elegant. I am about not to like python!

Comment: the solution depends on how you want to use `i` and `j`, are they supposed to index 2 different lists ? Or you need the values to calculate something else ?

Comment: in my case it is one array but in general that is just a iterator and shouldnot have to do with number of lists. not sure yet how python is handling more complex itertors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like

```
for (i,j) in zip(range(0,10,1),range(10,0,-1))
```

will work, but I do not really like it (it is ugly, isn't it ?). I am looking forward for an answer too.

Comment: yet better than other answers. what if I want to apply more logic? this includes range and steps only.

Comment: http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/ might help you

Answer (score 2):

In principle the following might be what you want:

```
for i, j in zip(i_list, j_list):
    ....
```

Comment: `for i, j in zip(range(10), range(10, 0, -1)):`

Comment: would u explain a bit.

Comment: In Python you can have any number iterators. In order to synchronise them one can use zip to create a tuple of every single combination. Alternatively you can write your own, elegant class which provides the iterator you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something super elegant, you can call `zip` on a `reversed` version of a `range` object.

```
r = range(10)
for i, i in zip(r, reversed(r)):
    print(i, j + 1)

0 10
1 9
2 8
3 7
4 6
5 5
6 4
7 3
8 2
9 1
```

Comment: how does reveres() work? does it bring O(n) computation?

Comment: @DragonKnight An iterator has information about the stop, step, and end. `reversed` takes that information and smartly generates a reversed version of what the original iterator would've generated.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know python has different type of writing a for loop
you can refer to this link https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop
and choice that fits your problem needs